# Intensive job in django view crashing gunicorn worker threads

Tags: django, gunicorn

I've got a django app that does a bit of processing to a photo when it is uploaded. This processing takes about 100ms.

I'm using Django running with gunicorn behind nginx.

Currently this is done synchronously, I use `subprocess` to invoke the processing, get the result and return the result within the frame of the HTTP request.

The problem is that although the actual processing only takes ~100ms, the view sometimes takes many seconds to return, causing gunicorn worker threads to crash with messages like:

```
2012-12-18 15:01:04 [31620] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:31626)
2012-12-18 15:01:05 [31620] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:31626)
2012-12-18 15:01:05 [31957] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31957
```

(Log level is `DEBUG`, and I get no further output). Sometimes it takes the whole webserver down.

Is there any way I can mitigate this problem? Currently traffic is not high enough to consider  putting the processing on a queue and communicating asynchronously (and even then, we'd want to block and still return within the context of the HTTP request).

Can anyone give insight into where the problem might be?

Comment: Without the code, it's hard to tell -- is the view either returning prematurely, or blocking on a worker thread returning?

Comment: Also, have you tried calling the view with the dev server (or gunicorn in a different thread mode)?

Comment: @fish2000 Not sure if I've got any code worth posting. The view isn't returning prematurely I don't think.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? I think I have the same problem here. The view is processed quiet fast but somehow the worker timeouts anyway...

Comment: @Anton I did fix this, I've posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) threads.

Answer (score 0):

For time consuming routines asynchronous execution is a good solution. The [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) library is well suited for this kind of job. And has a relatively low entry level.